# convert a docx file into pdf file using unoconv. It's taking too long and aborted

Tags: docx, libreoffice, pdf-conversion, unoconv, docx-to-pdf-conversion

convert a docx file into pdf file using unoconv. It's taking too long and aborted

**DOCX to pdf conversion command:**

```
 unoconv -f pdf -o sample.pdf sample.docx
```

[Download](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/4cabff5hqm4pisgsmxbnz/QL2877BC-0522-CCM-BC-Satisfaction-Survey_final-copy.docx?dl=0&rlkey=75t6mr9lpqwfhz9hzr91ubj6m) the sammple docx file

Comment: convert a docx file into pdf file using unoconv. It's taking too long and aborted